# How can I add a WHERE condition on a Text field in a SQLite query?

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite

I want to select some data by filtering on a Text field, but there is a problem.
If I change the WHERE condition to an Integer type, the problem goes away.
Is there a problem to add a WHERE clause with a Text field?

```
 Cursor cursor= sqLiteDatabase.query(tableName,columns,"Id=9" ,null,null,null,null);   this query is working very well But;
 Cursor cursor= sqLiteDatabase.query(tableName,columns,"whichWeek=Week 5" ,null,null,null,null);   this is not working. I don't understand :(


        db.execSQL(
                "create table "+tableName+" ( "
                        +Id+" integer primary key autoincrement,"+
                        evName+ " text not null,"+
                        depName+ " text not null,"+
                        evGol+ " integer,"+
                        depGol+" integer,"+
                        whichWeek+ " text not null );"
        );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your error:

```
"whichWeek=Week 5"
```

since it's a TEXT, you must enclose it in the TEXT delimiters ('):

```
"whichWeek='Week 5'"
```